# Как передать введенные значения из одного окна в другое?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Имеется **3** окна.

В первом окне (**glav.py**) две кнопки "окно 1" и "окно 2".
При нажатии на первую кнопку открывается окно `win1`, где я вывожу цифру **5** (с помощью кнопки) и пишу какой-нибудь комментарий в поле ввода.

В этом же окне есть кнопка "сохранить", которая должна передать введенные значения в окно `win2`.
Т.е. при открытии окна `win2` (**win2.py**) через главное окно `glav`, **2** поля будут заполнены значениями из окна `win1`.

Возможно ли это реализовать и как?

[image: интерфейс]

**glav.py**

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

    from win1 import MainWindow

    from win2 import MainWindow2

    class Ui_Dialog(object):

        def setupUi(self, Dialog):
            Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
            Dialog.resize(353, 308)
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 90, 121, 41))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
            self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 160, 121, 41))
            self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    
            self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    
        def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "главная"))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "окно 1"))
            self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "окно 2"))
    
    class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)
    
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)
            self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openWindow2)
    
        def openWindow(self):
            self.mainWindow = MainWindow()
            self.mainWindow.show()
    
        def openWindow2(self):
            self.mainWindow2 = MainWindow2()
            self.mainWindow2.show()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = Dialog()
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**win1.py**

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
        
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(542, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 140, 104, 71))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 101, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 160, 91, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 40, 113, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 542, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "окно 1"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "вывести число 5"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "сохранить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "комментарий"))

    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.rst)

    def rst(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText("5")




    if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**win2.py**

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
   
    class Ui_MainWindow2(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow2):
        MainWindow2.setObjectName("MainWindow2")
        MainWindow2.resize(461, 298)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 131, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 121, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 113, 51))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 150, 113, 71))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        MainWindow2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 461, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow2)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow2.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow2", "окно 2"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow2", "число из 1 окна"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow2", "комментарий из 1 окна"))

    class MainWindow2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow2()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, все возможно:

**glav.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from q1257770_win1 import MainWindow
from q1257770_win2 import MainWindow2


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(353, 308)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 90, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 160, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "главная"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "окно 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "окно 2"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openWindow2)
        
        self.mainWindow = MainWindow()                                          # +++
        self.mainWindow.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.updateWindow2)        # +++
        self.mainWindow2 = MainWindow2()                                        # +++

    def openWindow(self):
#-        self.mainWindow = MainWindow()
        self.mainWindow.show()

    def openWindow2(self):
#-        self.mainWindow2 = MainWindow2()
        self.updateWindow2()                                                    # +++
        self.mainWindow2.show()
        
    def updateWindow2(self):                                                    # +++
        self.mainWindow2.lineEdit.setText(self.mainWindow.lineEdit.text())
        self.mainWindow2.lineEdit_2.setText(self.mainWindow.plainTextEdit.toPlainText())    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]